# Terminating app due to -[GLKViewController loadView] loaded the "2-view-3" nib but didn't get a GLKView.'

Tags: ios

1. i am using OpenGL framework  in first time.Nothing i have written in code.
2. #import

@interface ViewController : GLKViewController

@end

Answer (score 9):

Delete the view from storyboard and add GLKView instead. It should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the xib that has been loaded doesn't contain a GLKView. Make sure you add a UIVIew and change the type to GLKView in the inspector panel on the right hand side of xCode.

Comment: how to change assign glkview to view

Comment: If your ViewController has a UIView as its main view and you have the GLKit framework in your app (should see it in Linked Frameworks), then look at the View's Identity Inspector in IB and change the custom class from UIView to GLKView

Answer (score 0):

The way that I created this error was:
I created a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` named: `ImageCollectionViewController` and then in storyboard, in the inspector panel I made the default ViewController to be of class `ImageCollectionViewController`.

**You can't do that!**
Because the viewController in Storyboard simply can't be implemented by a UICollectionViewController class instead you must use drag and drop a CollectionViewController from the interface builder into the story board and then in the inspector panel make it to be of class `ImageCollectionViewController`